# Get Url From CURL Response

Tags: php, regex

I have a respon using CURL :

```
{"code":200,"message":"Success","status":"success","data":{"payment_url":"http://dev.app.jualio.com/client/v2/payments/instant/AOXBE90WZY80VKDXF7M87FGGC","timestamp":"2017-02-22 12:37:36","expiry_time":"2017-02-25 12:37:36","status":"INITIATE"},"error":null}
```

How to get the payment_url?

Comment: Why is this tagged regex?! Surely you didn't plan to parse JSON with regex?

Comment: I am thinking of using regex. But I am not sure. Is the best way or not

Comment: decode the json response and then you will get an array then extract the value which you want? simple isn't it?

Comment: `$arr= json_decode($json_data, true); $url = $arr["data"]["payment_url"];`

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = json_decode($response);

if ($result) {
    echo $result->data->payment_url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$obj = json_decode('{"code":200,"message":"Success","status":"success","data":{"payment_url":"http://dev.app.jualio.com/client/v2/payments/instant/AOXBE90WZY80VKDXF7M87FGGC","timestamp":"2017-02-22 12:37:36","expiry_time":"2017-02-25 12:37:36","status":"INITIATE"},"error":null}', true);
OR
$obj = json_decode($curl_reponse, true);

echo $obj['data']['payment_url'];

// Output: http://dev.app.jualio.com/client/v2/payments/instant/AOXBE90WZY80VKDXF7M87FGGC
```

[Working Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5cd4a4b341dffce4b7e99317544c14a175287078)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    echo $data['data']['payment_url'];
?>
```